# Python + Beam + Flink

Tags: python, bigdata, apache-flink, apache-beam

I've been trying to get the Apache Beam Portability Framework to work with Python and Apache Flink and I can't seem to find a complete set of instructions to get the environment working. Are there any references with complete list of prerequisites and steps to get a simple python pipeline working?

Comment: Don't see any good docs to point to at the moment, but will these links help? https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/50f623c023f423aab1336aee136c36ef3c82d1ca/sdks/python/apache_beam/runners/portability/flink_runner_test.py#L40

https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/build.gradle#L347

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overall, for local portable runner (ULR), [see the wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/BEAM/Usage+Guide#UsageGuide-RunaPython-SDKPipeline), quote from there:

Run a Python-SDK Pipeline:

1. Compile container as a local build: `./gradlew :beam-sdks-python-container:docker`
2. Start ULR job server, for example: `./gradlew :beam-runners-reference-job-server:run -PlogLevel=debug -PvendorLogLevel=warning` . For details see the Java section in the above link.
   3 Set up python environment properly.  More details [can be found here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/BEAM/Python+Tips).
3. Run pipeline by using following (under folder sdk/python),

example:

```
python -m apache_beam.examples.wordcount\
  --input=gs://dataflow-samples/shakespeare/kinglear.txt \
  --output=/tmp/output \
  --runner=PortableRunner \
  --job_endpoint=localhost:8099 \
  --experiments beam_fn_api
```

For Flink you need to use a different job server: `./gradlew beam-runners-flink_2.11-job-server:runShadow`. The host:port is `localhost:8099`,

Relevant email discussions: [one](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/b2b97efaf1f4a6e283eaf92e05605f10f405e9eb9a9c41896041d0ac@%3Cdev.beam.apache.org%3E), [two](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/8dd60395424425f7502d62888c49014430d1d3b06c026606f3db28ab@%3Cuser.beam.apache.org%3E).

Possibly worth looking at some code: [one](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/50f623c023f423aab1336aee136c36ef3c82d1ca/sdks/python/apache_beam/runners/portability/flink_runner_test.py#L40), [two](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/build.gradle#L347).